# Reputation point calculation

Tags: support, reputation

Hello everyone. I recently asked a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17063/minimal-non-cyclic-groups-other-than-the-klein-four-groups)  and earned 7 upvotes but my rep point is 36. I can't figure out how it was calculated. It is not for rep points that I come to this site ; however, I want to reach the rep level where many privileges are enjoyed.

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I just knew that it is different here.(from MO)

Comment: Why the downvote to this question?

Comment: @Akhil: I didn't downvote, but perhaps because there was no indication that there was any prior research done? Like maybe reading the FAQ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Oh my gosh a math question I can actually answer! Let me try my hand at this:

(5 × 7) + 1 = 36

Comment: Jeff, you can't honestly expect mathematicians to be able and calculate simple multiplications!! :-D

Comment: You remembered me Poincare who usually missed simple additions.

Answer (score 6):

All's explained [in the FAQ](https://math.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation). 7 upvotes to your questions at 5 rep each gives +35. Everyone starts with 1. So you have a total of 36.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it was the same as MO.